# adding a new row when particular combination is not available, otherwise update a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with following structure

```
id         int             auto increment, primary key
uid        int             (comment: userid)
cdt        date/time       (comment: current date)
hits       int             (comment: no. of hits)
```

Now, I need a query such as

for a particular combination of 'uid' and 'cdt', if there is row available, then update hits (ie., add 1 to hits) otherwise add new row with 'uid' and 'cdt' values, and hits set to 1

Let me clear further with example

say uid = 01, and cdt = 2010-01-01, if this combination of uid and cdt is not available in table, then new row should be inserted, otherwise value of hits should be update

How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need ONE query or could you achieve your goal with more than one step?

Comment: I'm reading right now, after posting the answer... I see what can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in two steps:

**First:**
Query db to know if that particular record is present:

```
SELECT id FROM your_table 
WHERE uid = your_user_id AND cdt = your_date
```

**Second:**
If previous query returns zero rows:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
(uid, cdt, hits)
SELECT your_user_id, your_date, 1
```

else:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET hits = hits + 1
WHERE uid = your_user_id AND cdt = your_date
```

Comment: Thank You. Is it possible in one step?

Comment: can't be, is it not possible at all?

Comment: @I-M-JM: not for my knowledge, sorry. I've never seen something like the one you need... but that doesn't mean it's not possible, it simply means that I don't know how to do it. Sorry